# What is the normal way of dealing with non-standard library locations in an autoconf script?

Tags: opengl, build-automation, glut, autotools, autoconf

I'm trying to use the GNU autoconf/automake toolchain for the first time, so the answer to my question might be trivial.

The program needs OpenGL/GLUT where the headers and libraries are installed in a non standard location. I found [these](http://code.google.com/p/autoconf-gl-macros/) macros that should do all the checking for me. I'm simply calling it with *AX_CHECK_GLUT*. How do I make the macro find the libraries? I'm looking for something like

> ./configure --with-glut-dir=/home/hanno/glut

More generally: What is the normal way of dealing with non-standard library locations in an autoconf script? Of course, I can play around with CPPFLAGS and LIBS variables, but I have the feeling that I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way the Autotools are designed, a package author doesn't have to do anything to support prerequisite installed in non-standard locations.  The output of `./configure --help` includes the following lines:

```
LDFLAGS     linker flags, e.g. -L<lib dir> if you have libraries in a
            nonstandard directory <lib dir>
CPPFLAGS    C/C++/Objective C preprocessor flags, e.g. -I<include dir> if
            you have headers in a nonstandard directory <include dir>
```

Therefore, if the installer has a prerequisite installed in a non standard location, he will have to issue

```
./configure CPPFLAGS=-I/non-standard-dir/include LDFLAGS=-L/non-standard-dir/lib
```

Because `CPPFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` are used by `configure` checks and `Makefile` rules, everything should work.

Some package authors like to offer a `--with-`*package*`=location` option as a shorthand for the above, but this normally is not the purpose of `--with-`*package* options.  These options are better used [to specify whether an optional package should be used, or how a prerequisite should be fulfilled](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/html_node/External-Software.html).